# ng-click not working, trying to replace an image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm new of Angular JS, Well I'm trying to replace an image on click. i.e.,One Click on Img1 i would replace the previous image by Img1 and so on.

To achieve this I'm using ng-click. The thing is even the image names are being retrieved from DB.

So when I do this, it doesn't work-

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/{{oneItem.Image3}}" ng-click="current='{{oneItem.Image3}}'" />
```

Whereas works when I do this-

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/products/{{oneItem.Image3}}" ng-click="current='test3.jpg'" />
```

And I'm trying to replace it here-

```
<div class="trueimagger">
      <img ng-src="WebDrop/images/products/{{ current }}" />
</div>
```

Can someone help me out by pointing where I'm messing it up.

Please lemme know if any additional info is needed. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) expects an expression:

```
ng-click="current = oneItem.Image3"
```

You should also use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive instead of src attribute directly:

```
<img class="img-responsive" 
     ng-src="images/products/{{oneItem.Image3}}" 
     ng-click="current = oneItem.Image3" />
```

Comment: It worked...Brilliant..Who would have thought..Thanks a lot buddy :):):) Made my day..:):)

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write double curly braces `{{..}}` in `ng-click`.

Instead, simply write:

```
<img class="img-responsive" 
    src="images/products/{{oneItem.Image3}}" 
    ng-click="current='oneItem.Image3'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change it directly on the controller so you can format your url without putting logic on the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('yourApp', [])
      app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.imgSrc = 'http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg';
        $scope.changeSrc = function() {
          $scope.imgSrc = 'http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg';
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="yourApp">
      <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
        <div class="trueimagger">
          <img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}" />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="changeSrc()">ChangeImgSrc</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rrZKSF8eUx6SUqxvZoqK?p=preview) with this idea

Comment: That's a good idea, But here I'm trying to make a category page of a shopping site [link](https://s13.postimg.org/w4gb7jcef/snap.png) . So this cant help me much. :). Thanks for letting me know about it :)